# Hearing two different soundtracks on a VOB movie

Tags: video, audio, vob

I'm trying to watch a VOB movie, and I hear two sound tracks, one of the movie (low) and a second one that has nothing to do with the movie. I've had this in the past with several movies, it's just a bunch of people talking to each other, possibly an interview of some sort.

Why would I be hearing two distinct soundtracks?

Comment: The question here is if you have burned that to DVD or watching it on PC? Was the VOB downloaded via P2P which could point to bad ripping job.....

Comment: I know that VLC can tell you if the video has 1,2 or more audio tracks. You would want to either strip them use let VLC know which track to use.